# How to start an application using Python

Tags: python

I want to use a Python script to start an application, and then click File to Open a file. How should accomplish this? For example, I want to write a script which starts an automation tool/program that I have.

Is there another scripting language that is better suited for this?

You are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you basically want to load a program using python, if so you should try something like this:

```
import os
ACRORD = r"c:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 5.0\Reader\acrord32.exe"
os.system ('"%s" %s' % (ACRORD, r"c:\temp\blah.pdf"))
```

as found here also: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2004-April/001868.html

Comment: yes, thanks. but one more thing, if i want to run the file i opened, how should i do?

Comment: What type of file did you open?

Comment: Actually, i can open my scripts now by using your script above, i want to let sofeware run the scripts that was openned.
ie, i have some QTP script, i can use your script to open a script i wanted.But i want to know how to use script to let my tool run script that was openned. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a pure python solution you can explore [PyMouse](https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse), but you should really take a look at [Xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/), which is a software made specifically for automation tasks